# Run service at the midnight without launching the app

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

Here is the code

this function is calling from MainActivity.onCreate()

```
 private void setTheTimeToUpdateTables(Context context) {

        Log.i("Update table function","Yes");

        AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent alarmIntent=new Intent(context,UpdateTables.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,alarmIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);


        Calendar alarmStartTime = Calendar.getInstance();

        alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
        alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);

        Log.d("Alarm","Set for midnight");

    }
```

Here is the code for the updateTables

```
public class UpdateTables extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.i("Service Start", CalculateDaysService.TAG);
        Log.d("BroadCast Receiver","yes");

        context.startService(new Intent(context,CalculateDaysService.class));

        Log.i("Done","Yes");
    }
}
```

Manifest.XML

```
 <receiver android:name=".UpdateTables" android:enabled="true"/>
```

Not able to call the updateTable class.

**Update:**

private void setTheTimeToUpdateTables(Context context) {

```
    Log.i("Update table function","Yes");

    AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent alarmIntent=new Intent(context,UpdateTables.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,alarmIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);


    Calendar alarmStartTime = Calendar.getInstance();

    alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
    alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 29);
    alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    if (alarmStartTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) >= 10) {
        alarmStartTime.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis(),100*1000,pendingIntent);

    Log.d("Alarm","Set for midnight");

}


 <receiver android:name=".UpdateTables"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

**change**

```
 alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
```

**To**

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
```

**OR**

```
 alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
```

And for the broadcast reciever, you have configure **AndroidManifest.xml**

**set**

```
android:exported = true
```

[see this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html)

**UPDATE**

**AndroidManifest.xml**

**In `<manifest>` Tag**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

**in your `<application>` tag**

```
  <receiver android:name="com.yourpackage.UpdateTables">  
        <intent-filter>  
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
        </intent-filter>  
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Will it call without launching the app? @emdad

Comment: yes, updated the code a little giving the service to start when booting of the device is completed each time. and registered the event to the broadcast receiver. check the **updated** answer

Comment: What exactly means booting of the device is completed each time.

Comment: this means when ever the device is on the service will run. (device power on)

Comment: Bro I tried it with repeating in after 100 seconds but it is not working.

Comment: change
`alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 10000L, pendingToRun);`

this is for 10 seconds repeating alarm hope it helps

Comment: I update the updated code. getting no error.  but update table class is not calling

Comment: have you given your package name? correctly? in manifest receiver

Comment: change
`alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis(),100*1000,pendingIntent);`



to

`alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTI‌​ME_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 10000L, pendingToRun);`


or

`alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTI‌​ME_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 10000L, pendingToRun);`

Comment: your permission 

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />`

also check the permission

Comment: update the code, but not working. I also checked the permission.